# how to remove url parameters in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to rewrite this url http://myurl.com?key=somevalue to 
http://myurl.com/somevalue using .htaccess.
please help me ,thanks in advance

this is my code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?key1=/$1 [L,QSA]  in .htaccess file
```

Comment: Can you try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?key1=$1 [L,QSA] in .htaccess file (Removed "/" after =)

Comment: its not workingg..

Comment: Can you check if mod_rewrite is enabled in your server?

Comment: im new in php.. can you please tell me how to check..??

Comment: This is a trivial question answer to which you can [easily find on the Internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+check+if+htaccess+is+working). One of the important parts of programming is to learn how to search for the exact information you need.